# 301 редирект с учетом поддоменов

Tags: .htaccess

Нужна помощь в настройке редиректов. Есть сайт, назовем site1, и есть его зеркало, назовем site2. site2 является зеркалом site1. Оба сайта сделаны на WP с использованием опции Multisite. Нужно настроить htaccess там, что бы страницы site1 перенаправлялись на аналогичные страницы site2. Пример:

```
http://site1.com = http://site2.com
www.site1 = www.site2
http://domain.site1.com = http://domain.site2.com
```

Помогите с .htaccess, пожалуйста.

Comment: А не проще ли в этом случае без всяких редиректов? Если сайты "равны", то site2.com (domain.site2.com) сделать алиасом site1.com (domain.site1.com). Действие редиректа тут явно лишнее.

Comment: Дело в том, что через месяц site1 будет выключен, останется только site2.